# Rename files sequentially keeping first part of name

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, rename

I have these files:

```
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.0
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.1
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.2
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.3
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.4
```

And I'd like to rename like this:

```
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_1.csv
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_2.csv
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_3.csv
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_4.csv
NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_5.csv
```

I've tried the following (and some variations) but got no success:

```
rename -v 's/(NIHMS.+tons).csv.+/\1_[0-9]\.csv/' *.csv*
```

and

```
ls *csv* | sed -E 's/(NIHM.+tons)\.csv.*$/\1_{1..5}.csv/'
```

and

```
ls *csv* | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$f_$n.csv"; done
```

The closest I got was using the last one that gave me like:

```
1.csv 2.csv 3.csv 4.csv 5.csv
```

I'm pretty sure I can do this using python, but I'm trying via command line/bash and preferably using regex (which I'm trying to learn better).

Comment: This seems to increment the numbers by one, but the accepted answer doesn't. What is the desired behaviour really?

Comment: @Benjamin W. I explained what I wanted in question itself and I even posted an example of the desired output. The last thing I said was to exemplify what I got that wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: Yes, according to the desired output in the question, the numbering changes from 0,1,2,3,4 to 1,2,3,4,5, but the accepted answer maps directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new name with sed, saving sections of the filename and swapping them:

```
for file in *.csv.[0-9]*; do
  new_name=$( echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.csv\.\([0-9]*\)/\1_\2.csv/' )
  echo mv $file $new_name
done
```

For safety, I put in the echo in front on the mv.  If the results look good, take out the echo.  Here are my results:

```
[jack@marta ~]$ for file in *.csv.[0-9]*; do new_name=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.csv\.\([0-9]*\)/\1_\2.csv/'); echo mv $file $new_name; done
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.0 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_0.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.1 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_1.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.10 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_10.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.11 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_11.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.2 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_2.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.3 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_3.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.4 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_4.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.5 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_5.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.6 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_6.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.7 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_7.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.8 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_8.csv
mv NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons.csv.9 NIHMS735398-supplement-Supplemental_Table_-_Top_Down_MS_Identificaitons_9.csv
[jack@marta ~]$
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is by using bash parameter substitution:

```
for f in *.csv.* ; do d="${f##*.}" ; mv "$f" "${f%*.csv*}__$((d+1)).csv" ; done
```

The `d` variable gets set to the last digit in the filename, then replaces it in the `mv`.

Comment: The number doesn't get incremented here, does it?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: No, it uses the one from the filename.

Comment: But it should be incremented, if you look at the desired names.

Comment: Input: 0,1,2,3,4; output: 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @BenjaminW. : It appears the correct answer is not to increment the number, so downvoting question since it wasn't made clear.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash regular expressions:

```
re='(.*)\.csv\.([[:digit:]]+)$'
for f in *; do
    [[ $f =~ $re ]]
    echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1 )).csv"
done
```

The `echo` can be removed when the output seems correct.

If the goal is not to incremenent the input file number, but have sequentially numbered files starting from 1, the code can be changed to the following:

```
re='(.*)\.csv\.[[:digit:]]+$'   # Just one capture group
i=1
for f in *; do
    [[ $f =~ $re ]]
    echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$(( i++ )).csv"
done
```

Now the files will be numbered 1, 2, 3, ... in alphabetical input order.

Answer (score 0):

Untested as I am not at a computer, but based on your own efforts with `rename`, this should be close:

```
rename -n '($a,$b)=split /.csv./; $_=$a . ($b+1) . ".csv"' *csv*
```

The `split` should put everything before ".csv." into `$a` and everything after it into `$b`. The second part sets the output (`$_`) to `$a` followed by `$b+1` with ".csv" appended.